# Can $\zeta(s)$ be written in the form $\zeta(s)=\Re(\zeta(s))+i·\Im(\zeta(s)) $ for some subset of $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

Can $\zeta(s)$ be written in the form $\zeta(s)=f(s)+g(s) i $ for some subset of $\mathbb{C}$? I mean, is it possible to develop at least one of the formulas of $\zeta(s)$ so you get something like...

$$
\zeta(s) = \Re(\zeta(s))+i·\Im(\zeta(s)) \; \;
\\ \text{or} \\
\zeta(s) = \Re(\zeta(s))+i·\Im(\zeta(s))+ (\text{some-complex-function-that-you-can-keep-solving})
$$

Being $\Re(\zeta(s)):\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\Im(\zeta(s)):\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  both real functions. 
Concerning the domain of the function, I am not really interested in all complex numbers: just if there is a subset that allows this rearrangement of the formula. I just let you a clear analogy:

$$
e^{ix}=\text{cos}x+i·\text{sin}x
$$

This is the thing that I want to know. I've been looking in internet (this is not my field) but I haven't found **anything** about this- I'm still looking for an explicit representation of the real and imaginary part of the $\zeta(s)$ function as real real functions. Could anybody help me?? Thanks!!

Comment: I do not get the question. Obviously you can split $\zeta$ into real and imaginary part.

Comment: I don't know anything about the zeta function, but your alternative statement  doesn't mean much. You can set $\text{some complex function } = \zeta(s)-f(s)-g(s)i$.

Comment: @quid Maybe he means some representation of $\Re \zeta$ and/or $\Im\zeta$ as other known functions or series?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean. My question requires an edit, obviously.

Comment: I think the only notation we have is $\Re\zeta(s)$... maybe $\displaystyle\frac12\left(\zeta(s)+\zeta(\ \overline s\ )\right)$ if we don't like the $\Re$ symbol.

Comment: @CarlosToscano-Ochoa If you take as subset of $\mathbb{C}$ the set of even numbers, then it's possible to write Zeta as you said, because in that case we have a closed form. But it's a very particular case.

Comment: So it cannot be done far beyond even numbers, or it wasn't important/necessary at all. Thank you very much, @MarcoCantarini